# AWS Flow Framework, .get on Promises waits forever

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-web-services, promise

I'm using the samples for the AwsFlowFramework, specifically [helloworld](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/helloworld) and [fileprocessing](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/fileprocessing). I have followed all [the setup instructions given here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html). All the client classes are successfully created with the aspect weaver. It all compiles and runs.

But trying to do `.get` on a Promise within an asynchronous method doesn't work.  It waits forever and a result is never returned.

What am I doing wrong?

In particular the helloworld sample doesn't have any asynchronous method nor does it attempt to do a `.get` on a Promise. Therefore, it does work when copied outright and I can see in the activities client the "hello world" message printed. Yet, if I create a stub Asynchronous method to call `get` on the  `Promise<Void>` returned by `printHello`, the client of the activities is never called and so the workflow waits forever. In fact the example works if I set the returned promise to a variable. The problem only arises if I try to call `.get` on the Promise. The fileprocessing example which does have asynchronous methods doesn't work.

I see the workflows and the activity types being registered in my aws console.

I'm using the Java SDK 1.4.1 and Eclipse Juno.

---

My list of unsuccessful attempts:

- Tried it with Eclipse Indigo in case the aspect weaver does different things.
- Made all asynchronous methods private as suggested by [this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=99636).
- If I call `.isReady()` on the Promise this is always `false` even if I call it after I see the "helloworld" message printed (made certain by having a sleep in between). This leads me to think that `Promise.get` blocks the caller until `Promise.isReady` is `true` but because somehow this is never true, the client is not called and the workflow waits forever.
- Tried different [endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#swf_region).

Comment: @seanbreeden I appreciate you trying to improve the question but please do not change the meaning of the question itself. In particular, `printHello` returns `Promise<Void>` which is correct. The problem is trying to call `get on the Promise` as I specify in the question, no matter whether the type of the `Promise` is `Void`, `String`, or anything else.

Comment: My bad.  I'm not sure if you were aware but Void wasn't showing up at all before.  It was blank since SO was rendering it like a html tag.

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My very bad. I had a misconfiguration in the `aop.xml` file and so the load aspectj weaving for the remote calls was not correct.

Comment: what was the misconfiguration?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot find this anymore. You should do fine with AWS's tutorial.